# Neither ng-hide nor ng-show change the visibility of the element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I began to use AngularJS, and I decided to make a list appear when I click on a button.
My code is rather simple, but it doesn't work, and I don't understand why:

```
<div ng-app="myGame" ng-controller="gameCtrl">
    <h1>{{showLevels}}</h1>
    <p ng-show="showLevels">
        <ul>
            <li>Level 1</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 3</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Begin Game !</button>
</div>
```

And, in the JavaScript file:

```
var app = angular.module("myGame", []);
app.controller("gameCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.showLevels = false;
    $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.showLevels = !$scope.showLevels;
    };
});
```

The levels are always shown, whether I use the `ngShow` or `ngHide` directive, despite the fact that `$scope.showLevels` is toggled, as I can see next to the title.

Where does this problem come from?

Comment: change your tag  <p ng-show="showLevels">
  
        </p>
to div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [paragraph element `<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) can only accept [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content), and the [unordered list element `<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) is not such a content.

Therefore, your browser translates your code into another one making more sense for it, by taking the `<ul>` out of the `<p>`. Your HTML is in fact:

```
<p ng-show="showLevels"></p>
<ul>
    <li>Level 1</li>
    <li>Level 2</li>
    <li>Level 3</li>
</ul>
```

That's why your list is always visible, no matter the content of the `$scope.showLevels` variable. The solution is to use another element, a [document division element `<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) for instance, or to remove this intermediate element completely:

```
<ul ng-show="showLevels">
    <li>Level 1</li>
    <li>Level 2</li>
    <li>Level 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I expected <p> and <ul> to have such problems, but didn't expect them to cause the browser to split it.

Thanks !